# Can Unix Executables be turned into an App for mobile devices?

Tags: xcode, unix

I was wondering if programs made for the command prompt/ terminal could be converted into a mobile app. Is there a way for the phone to run a terminal based program?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Which mobile phone are you talking about specificaly? You know, there's more than one of them.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, the galaxy s3, or maybe an apple device....

Answer (score 2):

No.

I added this bit cos SO wouldn't let me just post "No".